# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: The Testng.xml file upon executing is unable to trigger Priority=2 method

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, frameworks, testng

I Have Created a **maven** project and created `Main` and `Business` libraries for the page i want to automate. I have called the final methods in **testng** and `run->testngsuite`

My program is not showing errors but it is creating an exception. The element I want to hit is visible and has a static id . I have used all types of waits: `thread.sleep`, **implicit** wait and **explicit** waits. After serious observation, I observed that the `@test (priority =2)` method is the test throwing the exception. My program is perfect and there are no errors. Can any one help me if the **testng** needs any settings changes? I even checked if i have give any exclude test command as well, but the settings dont show any such excludes.

My **testng** program::

```
@BeforeSuite
public static void launchBrowser_tc01()
{       VerifyHomeButtons_TS_02.openbrowser_tc_01();    }



@Test(priority =0)
public void clickOnFitnessbtn_tc_02() 
{       VerifyHomeButtons_TS_02.clickOnFitnessBtn_tc_02();  }

@Test(priority =1)
public void clickOnDietbtn_tc_03()
{     VerifyHomeButtons_TS_02.clickOndietbtn_tc_03();   }
@Test(priority =2)
public void clickOnillnesbtn_tc_04()
{       VerifyHomeButtons_TS_02.clickOnillnessbtn_tc_04();  
}

@Test(priority =3)
public void clickOnstressbtn_tc_05()
{       VerifyHomeButtons_TS_02.clickOnStressbtn_tc_05();   }
@Test(priority =4)
public void clickOnlyfstylebtn_tc_06()
{       VerifyHomeButtons_TS_02.clickOnlifestylebtn_tc_06();    }
```

My exception:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element  is not clickable at point (821.5, 138). Other element would receive the click: 
>   Command duration or timeout: 105 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'Kushal-PC', ip: '192.168.171.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=47.0.2, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>   Session ID: e1727ab3-37a2-460d-b79c-f48520607b17

Please note.. if I re order the methods, the method which falls under priority 2 gets an exception.

Comment: Check the `testng.xml` & `pom.xml`. There must be some dependency or exclusion. Thanks

Comment: The title says `ElementNotVisibleException` but the stack trace you posted shows `WebDriverException ...blah blah... Other element would receive the click`. Assuming the latter is the actual error you're seeing, this usually happens if you're waiting for a popup or a screen overlay to disappear. If you can provide some information about what the test is doing, and what step it's failing on that would be necessary to narrow down what is happening.

Comment: Does this test pass when you run it by itself, or re order it?

Comment: As you mention Error stack you need to proved wait to bec it's click on some div layer over ur element. put wait in ur Test priority 2 method before calling it

Comment: @AnkurSingh i have mentiond webdriver wait, implicit wait and normal wait as well.., but the 2nd test does seems to be hitted.

Comment: @mrfreester yes the test is a pass when run individually.., only while using TestNg.., The 2nd priority is not triggering even after i reorder...,

Comment: @mrfreester The test is about hitting on some buttons on a webpage and when popup opened take a screenshot and close.., The same code i have written for 5 different buttons, all the buttons are triggering expect the one which i placed under priority 2.., irrespective of what button is mentioned there.., even if i re order them i see the other button placed under it is not hitted

Comment: @DebanjanB found no such exclusions.., can u help where and how to find them??

Comment: Show `VerifyHomeButtons_TS_02` class and `clickOndietbtn_tc_03` method please. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Problem solved without doing any changes. Thanks for the help anyway